# Stop ngModel to update view text

Tags: angular

I want to prevent ngmodel value to be updated at one place:

```
<div class="property-name">
    <span [innerText]="property.Name"></span>
</div>
<div class="property-value">
        <input [(ngModel)]="property.Name" (ngModelChange)="setGroupChange(property)" required>
</div>
```

In the above example, I don't want [innerText] to be updated while typing, but only when I save.

Answer (score 1):

This will update the model when focus out from input box

```
<input [(ngModel)]="name" [ngModelOptions]="{ updateOn: 'blur' }">
```

Or if you only want to change the text on `save` button  clicked, declare two variables and assign the value to target variable on click `save` button.

Comment: that would be too much trouble. I thought angular might have some kind of reverse one-way binding where once a value is assigned, it will not change.

Comment: Actually, it is there. If you bind like `[ngModel]="name"` it means one way data binding.

Comment: Thanks. I guess will have to use a temporary variable in any case.